# Laravel get array item by a value matching X in PHP, Google Analytics reporting api

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with the Google Analytics reporting api. I've performed a query and have the data that I need. The reporting api doesn't provide keys for the values returned in each array item, and the order of the items may not always be the same.

Given the attached structure, I'd like to search my `scheme` key for a value and pull out that one, I've tried using the `collect` function but couldn't get the right query there.

Data

````json
[
    {
        "date": "2022-02-03",
        "scheme": [
            [
                "Application (journey:continue): form loaded",
                "21"
            ],
            [
                "Application (journey:continue): started",
                "30"
            ],
            [
                "Application (journey:continue): submission:submitted",
                "7"
            ]
        ]
    }
]```

Then, for example:

```php
array_search('form loaded', $data['scheme']);
````

I want:

```json
[
    "Application (journey:continue): form loaded",
    "21"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` function as simple solution:

```
$res = array_filter(
    $data[0]['scheme'],
    function($el) {
        return strpos($el[0], 'form loaded') !== false;
    }
);
```

[PHP array_filter test online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/a35c495330dd983e393520d3251312fc/)